# Get LinkedIn group members email addresses in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, api, linkedin-api, group-membership

I want to extract LinkedIn group members' email addresses. (Note: I do not own the groups; they are just groups that I am a member of). I could not find anything yet to do so in LinkedIn API. Although I am able to get my current status, update status, friends list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around 4 years ago it was possible to get email addresses of members who joined your group if the group was set to private. Now there is no way to access this data apart from being a connection with all of the members of the group or viewing each members profiles and grabbing any email address that they have listed publicly.